# Is there a difference between "отель" and "гостиница"?

Tags: выбор-слова, лексикон

Is there a difference between words отель and гостиница? Can I always use either of them for some given estate?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, they are interchangeable but `oтель` has subtle connotations of something more if not luxurious but at least of higher class, so one can hardly name something very shitty `отель` ( unless it is actually has `отель` in it's name)

But actually `гостиница` is widely used in all contexts as well. You can say in a luxury hotel and Russian native-speaker will have no troubles calling it just `гостиница`.

Also, those two words a easily used together, just not to sound too repetitive:

> Отель «Премьер» расположен в центре рабочего поселка Кантемировка. ... Здание гостиницы оборудовано пожарной сигнализацией

So, answering your question, `гостиница` is applicable whenever `отель` can be used, almost in all cases it works the other way around as well. I'd rather stick to `гостиница`.

As a sidenote, [actually](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0) `отель` was more popular word but then it lost to `гостиница`.

[image]

Comment: I'm native Russian and I always say гостиница.

Comment: "As a sidenote, actually отель was more popular word but then it lost to гостиница." - probably western hotels were called отель, while Russian hotels were called постоялый двор or трактир.

Comment: @user31264 насчёт трактира я не уверен, но про постоялый двор - да, похоже - http://imgur.com/a/6YAUn

Comment: Трактир вполне мог служить гостиницей: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=остановился+въ+гостинице%2Cостановился+въ+трактире%2Cостановился+на+постояломъ&corpus=12&year_start=1800

Comment: PS: Корпус нашёл фразу "Я ночевал в трактире на Rigi-Staffel и на другой день всходил на самую вершину горы (Rigi-Kulm), чтоб видеть первую минуту солнечного восхождения." (Жуковский, 1821)  В ходе дальнейших поисков обнаружилось в "Станционном смотрителе": "Вскоре узнал он, что ротмистр Минский в Петербурге и живет в Демутовом трактире."

Comment: @user31264 вы правы, более того, оказывается в начале 19-го века именно этот вариант самый популярный - http://imgur.com/a/x1sqU